# ruby 2.2 gem dns error

Tags: ruby, dns, rubygems

i just installed ruby 2.2 on windows and try to install some gems, but i always get this error:

```
gem source -a http://somesource.com/rubugems
ERROR: While executing gem ...(Errno:EACCESS)
permission denied - sendto(2) for "255.255.255.255" port 53
```

i also tried this on a ubuntu server, same error, but as dig into it , it seems like a DNS problem, when i check my `resolv.conf` , the first line is `"255.255.255.255"`, so i remove it ,and everything is good on ubuntu.i try to do the same on windows : set the same DNS server manully , the `nslookup` command works fine ,but still got the same error.

anyone has any clue? thanks.

Comment: what is http://somesource.com/rubugems a private gem server?

Comment: you need to put a valid ip address for a dns server in place of that 255.255.255.255 line

Comment: @Kris yes actually a mirror.

Comment: @user3788685 for ubuntu i delete the "255.255.255.255", but for windows  i don't see it anywhere.

Comment: you could try 8.8.8.8 or 4.4.4.4 (I think) which are googles DNS's servers - your dns server should be listed as your router, or ISP if you do an `ipconfig /all`

Answer (score 0):

just found the cause: i have an openvpn client on my PC, whenever i created a vpn connection, a tap0 network interface i created, and the DNS for that interface is '`255.255.255.255`'

when ruby2.2.2  trying to find the DNS server for my machine , it uses `Win32::Resolv.get_resov_info` to get a list dns server, and the first one is `'255.255.255.255'` from my vpn interface.

later on when it try to resolve a gem  server , it try to use the '255.255.255.255' but without proper exception handling(only timeout exception), so i got the error without even trying the remaining proper dns server from other network interface.